# check whether an array contains a regex that matches with a string, using reduce

Tags: javascript, regex, reduce

I have a list of regex in JavaScript like the one below:

```
var list = [
 '^/items/detail.*',
 '^/items/settings.*',
 '^/article/view/.*',
 '^/home/purchase.*',
];
```

I want to see if a string matches one of the regex in the array.
if possible, I'd like to use reduce.

I've tried this:

```
var text = "http://www.mypage.com/items/detail";
var result = list.reduce((a, b) =>
  !!text.match(a) || !!text.match(b)
);
```

but doesn't seem to work. For some reason it returns false. I've tried different variations and couldn't find one that works.

Comment: How about `some` instead of `reduce`? Do you need to know what regex matches, or that at least one does?

Comment: As Andy mentioned, `some` seems to be more appropriate for this scenario. `var result = list.some(t=> text.match(t));` , but you'll have to alter the regexes and remove the 'startswith' `^` , otherwise the expressions won't match. (http://jsfiddle.net/28rzph21/ )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use **[`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** and add an additional condition `a === true` since `a` will be true or false on second iteration

```js
var list = [
  '/items/detail.*',
  '^/items/settings.*',
  '^/article/view/.*',
  '^/home/purchase.*',
];

var text = "http://www.mypage.com/items/detail";
var result = list.reduce((a, b) =>
  a === true || (a !== false && !!text.match(RegExp(a))) || !!text.match(RegExp(b))
);

console.log(result)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

More simplified version as suggested by ***@zerkms***, by providing an additional **[`initialValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** as `false`

```js
var list = [
  '/items/detail.*',
  '^/items/settings.*',
  '^/article/view/.*',
  '^/home/purchase.*',
];

var text = "http://www.mypage.com/items/detail";
var result = list.reduce((a, b) => a || RegExp(b).test(text), false)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: To avoid ugly `typeof a == 'string'` one would pass the `false` as the initial value.

Comment: @zerkms :  on first iteration `!!text.match(a) || !!text.match(b)` will be return as `true` or `false`, so in the second iteration value of a will be `boolean`

Comment: Sure, and for that very reason you initialise it with `false` explicitly so that the accumulator always was of the boolean type.

Comment: `list.reduce((a, b) => a || RegExp(b).test(text), false)`

Comment: @zerkms :  I were confused first, now I got it... thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is another way I found (but without reduce :( )
`list.filter((a) => path.match(a)).length > 0`